# Can't access files ('.Files') using helm subchart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a sub-chart which is being used by many other Charts, the sub-chart has a Deployment file in it that is using [access files](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/).
The deployment includes the following line `{{- range $value := .Files.Lines "test.list" }}` and `test.list` file is under the **main chart**.

```
MAIN CHART
├── Chart.yaml (with dependency for the sub-chart)
├── values.yaml
└── test.list

SUB CHART
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   ├── deployment.yaml (including the {{- range $value := .Files.Lines "test.list" }}
└── values.yaml
```

Unfortunately, the `test.list` file is being ignored unless I am moving it inside the sub-chart. Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: hi, has this problem been solved, I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Your question helped me to figure out my own issue: I could not get the .Files.Glob to use the sub-chart's files, it would only find files in the main chart.

My solution is to not use named templates from the sub-chart.

Maybe it is an option for you to put the .Files.Lines into a named template in the sub-chart and include it into the main chart. That way the .Files will be run in the context of the main chart.